# Git subtree: Push new changes to origin

Tags: git, github

I used the following git subtree command to do the initial push to the remote repository from local subtree:

```
git subtree push --prefix=src origin master
```

After applying some changes to the code I did `git commit` and `git push -f` however when doing `git push` I get errors: `Large files detected.` I wonder if I should use a different push command because I am working with git subtrees.

Comment: I doubt that this a subtree-specific problem.  More likely, you just have large files, which Github is rejecting.  (Indeed, the rest of the error message probably tells you exactly which files are causing the problem.)